# Two flights with the same number and same destination, 15 minutes apart

Tags: air-travel, bookings

I booked seats with Thomas Cook airlines. I tried booking another seat on the same flight but it was fully booked. I booked a seat on the next flight.

I received confirmation of the two different flights. Both flights are with the same airline, departing from the same airport, but departing 15 minutes apart. Both have the same flight number, ie MT508. Is this normal?

Comment: Are you sure they're flying on the same day?

Comment: What date(s)?  This is NOT normal, and if correct would likely cause some level of chaos at the airport...

Comment: https://www.airportia.com/flights/mt508/london/dalaman/ shows there's only one MT508, and it's a weekly flight. Something's wrong here...

Comment: Try calling the airline to make sure your seat is real. Sounds like a glitch in the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

That is uncommon, but it does happen. Although normally they have different flight numbers.

I had two other examples just this month (COPA from MCO to PTY, and then PTY to LIM - there are each two flights within 15 minutes, and yes, they were boarding at two neighboring gates, into separate planes).
I guess some connections just draw more customers for a certain time of the day than can fit in one plane.

What is possible is that the flight was moved, and one of the two you see now is the old one (before the moving), and the other is the new one. If the planes are different types, the airline is busy for some hours moving all passenger to new seats, and they simple lock the old one as full during that time. Once they have rebooked everyone, the old one will be removed.

Comment: On charter it could happens on high demand periods.Or on small aircraft, when there is very high demand. Sometime they have also the same departure time.

Comment: Two flights to the same location leaving at very similar times is indeed very common.  Those flights having the same flight number - which is the question that was being asked here - is NOT.

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely not normal. MT508 flies only on Sundays at 21:45 o'clock. You can see its past history here: https://planefinder.net/data/flight/MT508 and the current time table here https://www.thomascookairlines.com/en/book-plan/flight/timetable/timetable-result.jsp?dd=20180625&rd=&oneway=1&o=LGW&d=DLM&action=search&flightMode=OW

Check the time table and make sure that the flight that you have booked shows up there.